# Android OnActivityResult setVisibility

Tags: android, visibility

I have two buttons with in the same activity. Each buttons calls the recognizerIntent to do some speech recognition. What Im trying to accomplish if have the microphone Icons Image1 and Image2 be made invisible or gone if the correct word is spoken.

```
public class Cooking  extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    ListView lv;
    static final int check = 1;
    static final int checka = 2;


    int counter_score;
     int counter_score_b;
    TextView txView;
    MediaPlayer ourSong;
    ImageView display,image1,image2;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        counter_score=0;
        counter_score_b=0;
        setContentView(R.layout.cooking);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_1_wrong);
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_2_wrong);        
        initialize();





}


private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
    txView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);

    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_1_wrong);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_2_wrong);

    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);


    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
     actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

}




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.IVimage_1_wrong){
        Intent a = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        a.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        a.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
        a.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak");
        startActivityForResult(a, checka);
    }else if(v.getId() == R.id.IVimage_2_wrong){
        Intent b = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        b.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        b.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
        b.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak.");
        startActivityForResult(b, checkb);
    }
}


 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestCode == checka && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
            if(results.contains("cooking")|| results.contains("yes really") || results.contains("disease")){

                counter_score ++;
                    ///////I though this would make ImageView Image1 not be visible  
                image1.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
                ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Cooking.this, R.raw.rightsound2);
                ourSong.start();
                AlertDialog dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                dialogBuilder.setTitle("Good");dialogBuilder.setMessage("Correct");
                dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_mark);
                dialogBuilder.show();
                Thread timer = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        try{
                         sleep(2500);
                        }catch (InterruptedException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {





                        }
                    }
                };
                timer.start();

            }else{

                lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
                counter_score +=0;

                counter_score_z +=0;
                ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Cooking.this, R.raw.wrongsound);
                ourSong.start();
                AlertDialog dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                dialogBuilder.setTitle("Oops");
                dialogBuilder.setMessage("Error msg");
                dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_wrong);
                dialogBuilder.setButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        Intent openMovilTeacherApp = new Intent(Cooking.this, LetterEx.class);
                        startActivity(openMovilTeacherApp);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                dialogBuilder.setButton2("Try again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialogBuilder.show();
                Thread timer = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        try{
                         sleep(4000);
                        }catch (InterruptedException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {



                        }
                    }
                };
                timer.start();
            }



        }
        //////Delivering MAIL/////
        if (requestCode == checkb && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
            if(results.contains("delivering mail")|| results.contains("no not really") || results.contains("disease")){

                counter_score ++ ;
                 ///////// the next line was supposed to make the image2 no be visible, or gone
                image2.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
                counter_score_z +=1;
                ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Cooking.this, R.raw.rightsound2);
                ourSong.start();
                AlertDialog dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                dialogBuilder.setTitle("Good");dialogBuilder.setMessage("Correct");
                dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_mark);
                dialogBuilder.show();
                Thread timer = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        try{
                         sleep(2500);
                        }catch (InterruptedException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            Intent nextAct2 = new Intent(Cooking.this, LetterEx.class);
                            startActivity(nextAct2);
                            finish();



                        }
                    }
                };
                timer.start();

            }else{

                lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
                counter_score +=0;
                txView.setId(0);
                counter_score_z +=0;
                ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Cooking.this, R.raw.wrongsound);
                ourSong.start();
                AlertDialog dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                dialogBuilder.setTitle("Oops,");
                dialogBuilder.setMessage("Error Msg");
                dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_wrong);
                dialogBuilder.setButton("Continuar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        Intent openMovilTeacherApp = new Intent(Cooking.this, LetterEx.class);
                        startActivity(openMovilTeacherApp);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                dialogBuilder.setButton2("Try again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialogBuilder.show();
                Thread timer = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        try{
                         sleep(4000);
                        }catch (InterruptedException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {



                        }
                    }
                };
                timer.start();
            }



        }



        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



    }

}
```

My cooking.xml

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/small_right_blue_mic"
        android:id="@+id/image_1_wrong" 
       android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

     <ImageView android:src="@drawable/small_right_blue_mic"
        android:id="@+id/image_2_wrong" 
       android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Error log

```
08-29 17:15:54.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1953): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 17:15:54.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1953): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=222, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.testapp.app/com.testapp.app.Cooking}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: next line of error log is the line number of your code where the exception happened.

Comment: hmm ..ok thnx will look at that..

Comment: lol yeah..the error is at line 353, which is this line..image1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

so I guess you cant set visibility on OnActivityResult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you defined image1 and image2 locally. Change it like this. And you need to use findviewbyid() once only. thats enought

```
public class Cooking  extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    ListView lv;
    static final int check = 1;
    static final int checka = 2;


    int counter_score;
     int counter_score_b;
    TextView txView;
    MediaPlayer ourSong;
    ImageView display,image1,image2;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        counter_score=0;
        counter_score_b=0;
        setContentView(R.layout.cooking);
        image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_1_wrong);
        image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_2_wrong);        
        initialize();





}


private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
    txView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);


    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);


    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
     actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

}
```